# Python read() returns empty results

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

Whenever I'm trying to run this `python` code, it returns a blank result / empty result. Can anyone help me with understanding why this happens?

```py
#!/bin/python

import re
import time
import io

timecheck = open("/tmp/some.log", "r")
storeout = open("/tmp/storeout.txt", "w+")

for line in timecheck:
    if re.match("(.*)(Alarm obtained - type: KPI_CALCULATION)(.*)", line):
        out1 = line
        print >> storeout, line,

time1 = out1[11:19]
time2 = out1[164:172]
content = storeout.read()
print(content)
storeout.close()
```

Comment: please give us a log part

Comment: log file contains the below entry:

2020-11-23 13:10:57.596 petrosocial-esp-shutdown-handler DEBUG c.p.e.s.s.ShutdownAlarmConsumerService:54 - Alarm obtained - type: KPI_CALCULATION, time: 2020-11-23T12:51:00.000Z, KPI alarm type: KPI_CALCULATION
2020-11-23 13:12:31.245 petrosocial-esp-shutdown-handler DEBUG c.p.e.s.s.ShutdownAlarmConsumerService:54 - Alarm obtained - type: KPI_CALCULATION, time: 2020-11-23T13:12:25.000Z, KPI alarm type: KPI_CALCULATION

Answer (score 2):

When you write to a file, the current file position is located at the end of the file. If you call `read` without explicitly setting the file position, you'll get back an empty result because you're already at the end of the file.

To read the data you've already written, you need to instruct Python to start reading from the beginning of the file using the `seek` method:

```
storeout.seek(0)
content = storeout.read()
```

Alternately, you can `close` the file and then re-`open` it for reading.

Comment: Can anyone help with how this output can be sent via email.

Comment: You should probably post a new question if you want help with that.

Comment: Done, can you please take a look

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971241/sending-email-with-python-not-working-correctly